# Javascript File works for one HTML file but not the other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS file linked to my index.HTML file that works fine but it will not work for other .HTML file. Why is this. They elements I needs Javascript to apply to are the same and only have added ID tags on some of them. As I understand it, that should cause no issues as they have the same class name.

below are the first and second HTML files along with the JS file.

What am I missing here? I thought you could link to the same JS file as long as the HTMLs are the same and have a script tag to link to the JS file. Please help.

Working HTML File:

```
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Test 1</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <!--Navbar-->
<form action="#" id="formData">
    </form>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="inner-width">
          <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
          <button class="menu-toggle">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </button>
          <div class="navbar-menu">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
            <a href="#products">Products</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#training">Training & Support</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="careers.html">Careers </a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <h4>Account Number</h4>
                <form action="#">
                  <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <!--Back to top-->
      <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
      <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
    </body>
```

Not working HTML File:

```
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    
    <title>test file 2</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <!--Navbar-->
<form action="#" id="formData">
    </form>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="inner-width">
          <a href="/" class="logo"></a>
          <button class="menu-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </button>
          <div class="navbar-menu" id="cNavbar-menu">
            <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Log-in</a>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <h4>Account Name</h4>
                <form action="#">
                  <input type="text" class="acctNum" placeholder="Account Number" />
                  <h4>Password</h4>
                  <input type="text" class="passWord" placeholder="Password" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="login" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Create an Account" class="register" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <!--Back to top-->
      <button class="goTop fas fa-arrow-up"></button>
      <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
    </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formData');
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeIn();
    } else { 
      $(".navbar").removeClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $(".goTop").click(function () {
    scroll(0, 0);
  });

  $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("active");
  });
```

This is the code i've moved to it's own file. the Html file and JS have been unchanged.

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  }
  
  .inner-width {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  
  .navbar .inner-width {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .logo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 44px;
    background-image: url(../images/Full\ Logo\ white.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index:9999;
  }
  
  .menu-toggle {
    background: none;
    width: 30px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .menu-toggle span {
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  }
  
  .navbar-menu a {
    color:#f1f1f1;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
  }
  
  .navbar-menu a:hover {
    color: #d03228 !important;
  }
  
  .sticky {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 18px 0;
  }
  
  .sticky .logo {
    background-image: url(../images/Full\ Logo\ black.png);
  }
  
  .sticky .navbar-menu a {
    color: #111;
  }
  
  .sticky .menu-toggle span {
    background-color: #111;
  }
  
  /* Dropdown Button */
  .dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%; 
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #353b48;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content h4 {
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content .login {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #d03228;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content .login:hover {
    background-color: #d03228;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content .register {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #d03228;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
  }
  .dropdown-content .register:hover {
    background-color: #d03228;
    color: #fff;
  }
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  .goTop {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #d03228;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    display: none;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .menu-toggle {
      display: block;
    }
  
    .navbar-menu {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #353b48;
      top: 0;
      right: -100%;
      max-width: 400px;
      padding: 80px 50px;
      transition: 0.3s linear;
    }
  
    .navbar-menu a {
      display: block;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 30px 0;
    }
  
    .sticky .navbar-menu {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  
    .navbar-menu.active {
      right: 0;
    }
  
    .menu-toggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      top: 4px;
    }
  
    .menu-toggle.active span:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    .menu-toggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      bottom: 14px;
    }
  
    .dropdown {
      width: 70%;
    }
  
    .dropdown-content
    {
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .inner-width {
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
  }
```

One major difference ive noticed since moving the navbar CSS is that the "Go to Top" Button now appears when you first load into a page rather than only appearing when scrolling down.

Adding Main CSS file below for more context.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::selection {
  background-color: #d03228;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #d03228;
}

/*home page*/
#home{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#videoBG {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #videoBG {
    
      width:100%;
      height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #videoBG { 
      
      width:auto;
      height: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #videoBG {
      display: none;
  }
  #home {
      background-image: url(../images/fuji.JPG);
      background-size: cover;
  }
  
}


Could someone explain why this is happening?
```

Comment: In your non working page, your script tag is using curly quotes `”` instead of standard quotes `"`. That is probably the reason. You can use single or double quotes but not special characters like curly quotes

Comment: I thought this was it as well after looking but after making the change the result still remains the same. the .JS still does not link. But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: If you rename your working file, does it still work with new name? If it does, than just compare the source, you are missing something there.

Comment: I tried this and there has been no change. I removed all the original code and re copied the same code and ran it. Still not linking the .js file. It's like it's not pointing to it in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this you have to write like this,

In the HTML file, you have to add one attribute id/class

```
 <form action="#" id="formData">
 </form>
```

In jquery/javascript "**use anyone it's up to you**"

```
//javascript 
var form = document.getElementById('formData');
//jquery
var form = $("#formData");

/*add your script code like this*/

form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit)
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeIn();
    } else { 
      $(".navbar").removeClass("sticky");
      $(".goTop").fadeOut();
    }
  });
```

Comment: @applecart it's working as per your need?

Comment: YES SIR!!!! That was it! page works 100% as intended! you rock! So what's the logic behind this? If the variables are being called from the index.html file why do I need to define a new variable to convert my <form>?

Comment: We are just retrieving the `form`  instant into variable just a thought if you have multiple `forms` on one page. so which one you have submitted.

Comment: I ended up having to claim the  <form action="#" id="formData">
 </form> in both my HTML codes but by doing so they both work. This is why I was confused because I had to do this for both and not just the HTML file that it wasn't working on.

Comment: So it looks like the JS code stopped working after i moved the NAV bar css into it's own file. Does the CSS file tie into any the JS or am i missing something?

Comment: What you have written could you please share?

Comment: Hello Jishan, Thank you for your help before. I have updated the original post with the updated informaiton. Please have a look.

Comment: I'm going to also add the beginning CSS code from the main style file. Maybe something there could be the issue. I've added it with the rest of the code. Once again thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome @applecart

Comment: Were you able to find anything? i Still can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Could you please check the `JavaScript` code?

Comment: I've rewritten it numerous times with no change to the result. It's like the Javascript partially works for the index.html file but refuses to work on any other page. I know it's not the declaration of the function as it is a var and not a const. 

I think it may have something to do with the .sticky CSS being moved but I fail to see how that can be an issue if the HTML calls that file. Any help would really be helpful.

Comment: You are trying to access jquery code in all pages?

Comment: Yes. But i'm not using Jquery just Javascript.

Comment: No worries about javascript. but your dom element is available on the home page and your are trying to access it about page it won't work.

Comment: OK now i'm confused. I got it working on other pages previously. How did moving the CSS cause this? Wouldn't the element not matter as there was no change to the HTML or JS? I'm sorry is i'm asking a lot of questions. I'm trying to resolve this issue while understanding the solution so not to run into it again.

Answer (score -2):

try deleted id="cNavbar-menu" in the unworked html